# Does regular expression has difference forms on different system?

Tags: android, c++

I'm working on a Android automotive system. Now our team want me to implement a function to search something in a map.

```
 char rgxArr[256];
 strcat(rgxArr, "[A-Z_0-9]*");
 strcat(rgxArr, name);
 strcat(rgxArr, "[A-Z_0-9]*");
 std::regex rgx{rgxArr};
 while (it != kNameMap.end()) {
    if (regex_match(it->second, rgx)) {
        matched.push_back({it->first, it->second});
    }
    it++;
 }
```

I test this function on linux(ubuntu 16) computer and get result successfully.

But when I push this tool to an Android P (maybe Q?) automotive system and run in a command line (via adb), search doesn't work. I found that `regex_match` never return true.

I have no idea how it works, I guess maybe regex on Android command line is different with it on other OS?

Hope experienced friends can share your ideas, thx.

//gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Comment: What is the initial value of rgxArr before you strcat anything into it?

Comment: For example, if i search "TXT", the regex finally be: [A-Z_0-9]*TXT[A-Z_0-9]*. This regex works on my computer but failed on Andoird automotive system.

Comment: if you search "TXT" the regex finally be: aewiy958425v4q234vq234v2q342qasdfasdf vasdfasdf[A-Z_0-9]*TXT[A-Z_0-9]*. Well, it *could* be. Can you figure out why?

Comment: Some (old) implementations of some compilers were broken (Mingw-gcc). State version of your compiler.

Comment: How do you know that `name` doesn't contain characters that need to be escaped in a regex? How do you know that `name` when concatenated with the other values isn't going to overflow rgxArr? What is the initial value of rgxArr before you strcat anything into it?

Comment: The name has a rule. It only contains uppercase letters, underscores and numbers. It is a test tool for our team so i don't need to consider overflow. The initial value can be critical. I didn't think about it. It may contains something before strcat. I will initialize it and try again.